# Checking Mobile Phone Input in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, mobile, sms, prediction

I have a system that accepts SMS texts (they contain a single word).

What I need to do is to check the incoming word for accuracy allowing for predictive texting alterations.
I imagine this can be done by some kind of lookup against a SMS dictionary, but I can't find any.

Also I need to find a way to ensure that the list of words that may be sent are not going to appear in the same list of potential SMS predictive alterations.

The incoming words have few constraints but I could possibly enforce a size limit of 7.
I have thought about using the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) functions but these may not be sound against the predictive text options.

Any ideas on best to do this?

Comment: can you tell a bit more about the context? In fact I am confused that this question is tagged with "PHP", but doing texting alterations does  make much more sense directly on the client where PHP is not available - I am getting something wrong...

Comment: @jamie0726 the input from a SMS is hitting a service written in PHP. So PHP was tagged as it is the language that will have to be able to perform the checking algorithm

Comment: so the user finishes the SMS text, submits it to the service, the service analyzes it and the result is send back to the phone?

Comment: I guess you could do something with Solr and ElasticSearch. Solr comes with a [Suggester component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) which could be used for this eventually.

Comment: @jamie0726 they are both good ideas but a normal dictionary suggest can be done with pspell and is language based, not weighted for input from mobile devices

Comment: I thought that you were looking for some "fuzzyness" as you were mentioning Levenshtein (which is btw far too slow in the PHP implemention, I had to use a c program when I used it to compare records). The autocomplete/suggest components of professional search engines offer more than a simple dictionary comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular predictive texting solutions are proprietary, and I don't think the kind of database you are talking about is publically available.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_text)

Have you seen [this](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itprnn/itap/) analysis of iTap and T9?